# Heroku gives BABEL_PARSE_ERROR and await gets Unexpected Reserved Word after deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, babeljs, messenger

I'm developing a Facebook messenger chatbot. after last deployment to the Heroku, I'm receiving the BABEL_PARSE_ERROR to my Heroku console and says await is Unexpected Reserved Word. my dependencies as below.. and I'm using node very latest version(16.14.0)

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.16.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "dotenv": "^14.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
}
```

The error I'm getting to my Heroku console...

```
/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/parser/index.js:93
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503358+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503359+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503359+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503360+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: /app/src/services/chatbotService.js: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (11:21)
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503360+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503361+00:00 app[web.1]: 9 |   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503361+00:00 app[web.1]: 10 |     try {
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503362+00:00 app[web.1]: > 11 |       let username = await homepageService.getFacebookUserName(sender_psid);
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503362+00:00 app[web.1]: |                      ^
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503362+00:00 app[web.1]: 12 |       let response = {
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503362+00:00 app[web.1]: 13 |         text: `Hey! ${username}. Pick your language:`,
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503363+00:00 app[web.1]: 14 |         quick_replies: [
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503363+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser._raise (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:150:45)
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503363+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.raiseWithData (/app/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/parser/index.js:93
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503358+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503359+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503359+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503360+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: /app/src/services/chatbotService.js: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (11:21)
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503360+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503361+00:00 app[web.1]: 9 |   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503361+00:00 app[web.1]: 10 |     try {
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503362+00:00 app[web.1]: > 11 |       let username = await homepageService.getFacebookUserName(sender_psid);
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503362+00:00 app[web.1]: |                      ^
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503362+00:00 app[web.1]: 12 |       let response = {
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503362+00:00 app[web.1]: 13 |         text: `Hey! ${username}. Pick your language:`,
2022-02-12T10:36:33.503363+00:00 app[web.1]: 14 |         quick_replies: [
```

Below is my code which referred to ...

```
const sendWelcomeNewUser = (sender_psid, response) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let username = await homepageService.getFacebookUserName(sender_psid);
      let response = {
        text: `Hey! ${username}. Pick your language:`,
        quick_replies: [
          {
            content_type: "text",
            title: "සිංහල",
            payload: "SINHALA",
          },
          {
            content_type: "text",
            title: "English",
            payload: "ENGLISH",
          },
        ],
      };
      await sendMessage(sender_psid, response);
    } catch (e) {}
  });
};
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

problem was solved! I haven't included the async to that function. as per that function should as below..

```
const sendWelcomeNewUser = (sender_psid, response) => {
  return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let username = await homepageService.getFacebookUserName(sender_psid);
      let response = {
        text: `Hey! ${username}. Pick your language:`,
        quick_replies: [
          {
            content_type: "text",
            title: "සිංහල",
            payload: "SINHALA",
          },
          {
            content_type: "text",
            title: "English",
            payload: "ENGLISH",
          },
        ],
      };
      await sendMessage(sender_psid, response);
    } catch (e) {}
  });
};
```

this was resolved my issue.